# Push and commit with git without history

Tags: git

Let's suppose i have made a lot of local commits.
I now want to push last commit to my online repository but i do not want the other users to see the last commits. I just want to push last version.

I also want to keep my local commits history.

Do you know if it is possible without having to create a branch ?

Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept this so it doesn't float around next to unanswered questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume your current branch is called `foo`.

1. `git checkout foo` to make sure you are on the `foo`-branch.
2. `git checkout -b foo-public` to create a new branch called `foo-public` and switch to it.
3. `git rebase -i bar` where `bar` is the hash of the commit **before** the first commit you created.
4. The previous command will have brought up a text editor. There you should replace all `pick` keywords with `squash`, **but not the first** `pick`.
5. Exit the editor and another one should appear, prompting you for the commit name. You can leave the name of the last commit if you want. Close the editor.
6. You can now publish the `foo-public`-branch. It will only have one commit, which contains all of your changes. Your `foo`-branch still has your complete history.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to merge commits on gitlab ?

Comment: Yes. However, rewriting the remote history is generally not a good idea, especially if multiple people are involved. If you want to do it anyway you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git). If my answer solved your problem please accept it.

Comment: thanks, i am working alone. Is there a Single command in order to merge commits on remote repository, without merging it in local repository ?

Comment: I know it's an old post, but for people who can't work this out even with this solution, like me, what I ended up doing was copy the whole repo in a new directory, delete the .git folder and start over the process of `git init' etc, as if it was a new repo.