# Push the Git Head without history, with submodules, without extensive rebase?

Tags: git

I have a git repository in a pathological state such that various checks fail with the deviations from the main branch, failures with LFS, and conflicts. However, the head of the repository works fine. I would like to take the current state and start over by making a new repository. How would I export the current head while cutting off the remaining history?

Ideally, I would like to keep the

1. Current state of the files
2. Keep current LFS files in LFS
3. Keep `.gitignore` configuration but disregard history ion `.git` folders
4. Keep submodules as submodules as submodules

I see that `git archive` will export but destroys all git structure and I don't expect to end up with a git repository afterwards. A similar question on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482544/how-can-i-use-git-archive-to-include-submodules-from-a-bare-repository)) discusses how to archive submodules but I don't want just a raw export, I want the submodules to still be submodules and just keep the head without history. Another question is very similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007918/push-and-commit-with-git-without-history) but the solution is to rebase and squash but I think I cannot apply all 5156 old commits because some LFS files have been lost.

Is there an easy way to do this? My thought is that I may have to archive then remake the submodules and import the ignores from the old file.